# Can Postgres DB engine optimize unioned subqueries?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am doing a union between 2 queries on Postgresql. This is for a search type GET request where the caller can specify some search criteria and give a maximum number of records to return and an offset. So, it might look something like this (it's a lot more complicated):

```
select q.*, count(*) Over() AS TotalRecords from
(
select name, birthdate, city from regularpeople where birthdate > @startDate and birthdate < @enddate
union
select name, birthdate, city from otherpeople where birthdate > @startDate and birthdate < @enddate
) as q
order by q.birthdate limit @limitCount offset @offset
```

Functionally this works. However, if the 2 sub selects get a lot of records (like millions) can the DB optimizer for Postgresql handle this or will it perform poorly?

Comment: Yes, you can see this when using EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) for this query

Comment: It will choose the plan it thinks is best.  Whether it will choose, or even consider, the one *you* think is best is not something we can answer since you didn't tell us what that is.

Comment: Look at the execution plan to find out.

Comment: Also... do you really need an `UNION`?

Comment: @TheImpaler - I probably do need the union so that the result can be ordered and returned in the correct order. We thought about trying to handle this as 2 distinct queries but the ordering and paging is a problem.

Comment: @FrankHeikens - As I'm not very familiar with postgresql, your suggestion to use "explain analyze" helped. Thanks!

Comment: I was thinking that `UNION ALL` is much faster than `UNION` since the engine doesn't need to remove duplicates. Maybe it could help.

Comment: @TheImpaler - Thanks for the "UNION ALL" suggestion, that helped the QEP a lot!